# Outlook 2007 freezes my system when I start it says it is "synchonizing folders"

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, crash

When I try to start Outlook 2007, my system freezes, and Outlook says it is "synchonizing folders".

I don't use exchange, and haven't seen any answers online.

I've tried turning off the exchange integration (right clicking my folders)

Since doing the latter, there is no longer an icon in the system tray when this is frozen (there was before)

UPDATE:

It seems my anti-virus program (comodo) was what was actually locking during Outlook file synch. I disabled that, and things seemed to settle down.

Comment: This question was just prodded by the Community user. Post your update as an answer and mark it as accepted, to stop this happening.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a corrupted .PST file. It's possible to recover it by running scanpst.exe on it while Outlook is stopped. Google (with Bing! :)) for "scanpst.exe" and you should find a guide to making it work.